# Why can't I access a Notes DB with manager access on the ACL?

Tags: database, lotus-notes, acl, lotus-domino

I have to make some changes to an application hosted within Lotus Notes 8.5.

The database normally resides on a Domino server so I've made a local copy with no encryption and ensured I have manager access in the access control list.

Yet, when I try to run the application for testing purposes, I get a dialog box stating "You are not authorised to run this application". This shouldn't be the case since manager is the highest level of access.

I've tried multiple solutions found on the net in just about every combination I can think of:

- copying with and without encryption.
- copying and not copying the ACL.
- copying the whole DB and copying design only.
- compacting the local DB with `ncompact` after removing encryption.
- restarting Notes frequently and regularly :-)

Nothing seems to work, Notes refuses to let me access the database. I have checked effective access of my user ID and it does state I have manager access but still no go.

How can I figure out *why* it's refusing to let me run the application?

Comment: In case roles are used in your database and restrict access then you have to set in ACL option "Advanced / Enforce a consistent ACL across all replicas" for **local** stored database.

Comment: @Knut, I suggest you make that an answer since it's solved the problem and I'd hate to see you go unrewarded. I'd like to see some more explanation if possible since the option appears to be irrelevant from reading it. I _copied_ the DB to local hence there are actually no replicas so I have no idea how that fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case roles are used in your database and restrict access then you have to set in ACL [option](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.notes.help.doc/DOC/H_ENFORCING_A_CONSISTENT_ACCESS_CONTROL_LIST_OVER.html&resultof=%22Enforcing%22%20%22enforc%22%20%22consistent%22%20%22consist%22%20%22access%22%20%22control%22%20%22list%22%20) `Advanced / Enforce a consistent ACL across all replicas` 
for local stored database.

It is specific to **local** databases that normally all roles are ignored. The consistent ACL option is the only way to make them work. [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=463&context=SSKTMJ&dc=DB520&uid=swg21084294&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct463lotus) is a detailed description how this option affects the access to a local database. It don't have to be necessary a local *replica* - it works the same way for a local *copy* too.

You have to be a bit careful about this option. You can exclude yourself from ACL changes setting this option without leaving/setting administrator access for you.